# Add a new credit card to paypal recurring payment profile

Tags: php, yii, paypal

I have a feature in my website that a user can change/update/add a credit card in his/her Paypal recurring payment profile. But while updating the profile nothing happens. Please help.
Code is as below:

```
require_once("paypal_pro.inc.php");
$paypalPro = new paypal_pro('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.gmail.com', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', '', '', FALSE, FALSE );
$paymentAction = urlencode("Sale");
$methodToCall = 'UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile';
$padDateMonth = str_pad(4, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$expDateYear =urlencode( 2018);      
$expDate = $padDateMonth.$expDateYear;
$nvpstr='&PAYMENTACTION='.$paymentAction.'&METHOD=UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile&PROFILEID=I-NGYJW5L1TLNV&CREDITCARDTYPE=VISA&ACCT=4111111111111111&CVV2=123&EXPDATE='.$expDate;
$resArray = $paypalPro->hash_call($methodToCall,$nvpstr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($resArray);
```

I am trying this with a sandbox account.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to tell where are you writing this code. Don't mind but your code looks like not as it should be:
1- Which version are you using (Yii1 | Yii2)? I guess Yii1

if you are using yii1 and you want to perform this stuff under profile update Action.

so lets consider "profile/update" Action. so there will be some thing like below under "ProfileController".

```
public function actionUpdate(){
//some thing will be placed here....
}
```

There are 2 ways to do it. one just do it along with the controller or user Hooks (recommended) so it will be under "Model afterSave" hook. some thing like that. you can use any extension / component / widget.

[Paypal Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/paypal/) can tell you how you can do it .

Comment: Yes, I'm using Yii1. Below is my output.

  `[TIMESTAMP] => 2016%2d11%2d04T19%3a13%3a05Z
  [CORRELATIONID] => 5c6026b1dedec
  [ACK] => Failure
  [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10001
  [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
  [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Timeout processing request`

Comment: did you try using the above extension, if you still wanna use same class... verify your urlencode method + check you are filling every required info some times we have some problem.


Also check you not using the same amount as it was currently set.

Note: Amount will only be added to update if you are changing it other wise exclude it.

Comment: Thank you for you time. There was a error with my url. I was sending `$methodToCall='UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile';` to `$paypalPro->hash_call($methodToCall,$nvpstr);` and attaching it again with `$nvpstr`. I just removed `&METHOD=UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile` from `$nvpstr` and it worked :).